# GAP: how to obtain the Young Symmetrizer?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, gap, young-tableaux

Given a partition $\lambda$ of $n$ and a standard Young Tableaux filled with numbers from $1$ to $n$ (e.g. increasing row by row), how does one obtain the corresponding [Young Symmetrizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_symmetrizer) using GAP?

I could imagine that GAP already has such a functionality built in, e.g. in the package [Specht](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/mathas/specht/specht.html). However I do not understand the language used in the package description. I would highly appreciate a pointer.

Comment: Specht is a package for GAP 3. It is porter to the modern version of GAP in a new package called hecke: https://gap-packages.github.io/hecke/. I suggest first to check if the functionality is available and explained there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the new package. I haven't quite been able to find this functionality in there thou, although it could be that it is phrased in another terminology.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if no such function exists as the symmetrizers will (at least I expect them to) have a support close to the whole group. Writing down a symmetrizer thus is expensive in terms of memory  if $n$ gets larger. If you really want a function for it for playing around for small $n$, let me know, and I'll write one.

Comment: That would be great! For my purposes I'm eventually looking to construct the primitive central idempotents of $\mathbb{Q}[S_k]$. As far as I know, GAP has the function 'CentralIdempotentsOfAlgebra()' - I could however not determine to what order of partitions the output corresponds to. I now realised that the function 'PrimitiveCentralIdempotentsByCharacterTable()' from the Wedderga package could help, if the output is in the order of the character table rows. In any case, having the Young symmetrizer to play with would help greatly to check what is going on.

Comment: I'm almost done writing that Young Symmetrizer function. In case it would be interesting to possibly integrate it somewhere, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very naive way of implementing the definition is:

```
YoungSymmetrizer:=function(lambda)
local f,n,sym,a,emb,pl,al,ql,bl,g;
  f:=Flat(lambda);
  Sort(f);
  n:=f[Length(f)];
  if f<>[1..n] then Error("not a tableau");fi;
  sym:=SymmetricGroup(n);
  a:=GroupRing(Rationals,sym);
  emb:=Embedding(sym,a);
  pl:=Stabilizer(sym,lambda,OnTuplesSets);
  al:=Zero(a);
  for g in Iterator(pl) do
    al:=al+ImagesRepresentative(emb,g);
  od;
  ql:=Stabilizer(sym,TransposedMat(lambda),OnTuplesSets);
  bl:=Zero(a);
  for g in Iterator(ql) do
    bl:=bl+SignPerm(g)*ImagesRepresentative(emb,g);
  od;
  return al*bl;
end;
```

I suspect that the dense support will make this infeasible for n much beyond 8 or 9.

Comment: that works great, thanks a lot!!